# Multiple summarized fields are appearing into both columns in crosstab (Crystal Report). (how to remove summarize field)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have one crystal report having "Cross Tab" table.

"Crosstab expert" shows as below: 
       columns: Title 
       Rows: order,Name 
       Summarize: Sum of amount, Sum of netAmount

when it render then it appears as below:

```
                     title 1          title 2
 1. name value   | [amount sum]  | [netAmount sum]
 2. name1 value  | [amount sum]  | [netAmount sum]
 3. name11 value | [amount sum]  | [netAmount sum]
```

Now, i want to edit above cross tab confirguration as follow: (Addition of "FundSource" field into row.

```
  columns: Title
  Rows: order,Name, **FundSource**
  Summarize: Sum of amount, Sum of netAmount
```

and problem arise as below: [Amount sum] and [netAmount sum] both the fields appear into each column instead of appear in separate column.

```
                     title 1                           title 2
 1. name value   | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]  | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]
 2. name1 value  | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]  | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]
 3. name11 value | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]  | [amount sum]   [netAmount sum]
```

Please suggest , How to remove "NetAmount sum" field from "Title 1" column and "Amount Sum" field from title 2 column.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I got resolve as below steps:

Select all of the summarize fields which needs to remove from each column. Then, Ctrl-Click, right-click and select Format Objects... and check the Suppress option. Click on OK - those values will now be greyed out.
and will not be appear.

Answer (score 0):

write a condition for both the columns **[amount sum]  | [netAmount sum]**

For [amount sum]

```
if title=title1
then [amount sum]
```

For [netAmount sum]

```
 if title=title2
    then [netAmount sum]
```

now use both formulas in crosstab expert